# How to add new fields / values to an existing entity in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

How can I add new fields or values or properties to an existing entity and store them in the same table?

`Customer` entity already exists and have fields as

```
 - id
 - name
 - lastName
```

Want to add `contactNumber` (as seen in the api structure below) to this existing `Customer` entity. **Don't want a new entity for `contactNumber`**
The expected request body is as below:

```
{
    "id": "int auto generated",
    "name": "String",
    "lasName": "String",
    "contactNumber":
    {
        "mobile":"long",
        "office":"long",
        "home":"long"
    }
}
```

How can this be achieved ? Checked some blogs related to mapstruct but not getting proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@Embeddable` :

```
@Embeddable
public class ContactNumber {
    private Long mobile;
    private Long office;
    private Long home;
    // getters, setters...
}
```

Customer Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String lastName;

    @Embedded
    private ContactNumber contactNumber;
    // getters, setters...
}
```

With this mapping three columns(`mobile, office, home`) will be added to the `Customer` table.

You can simply save the `Customer` with the request body in the question using `(@RequestBody Customer customer)` parameter:

```
@PostMapping(value="/customers")
public void saveCustomers(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
    customerRepository.save(customer);
}
```

For more information take a look at [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Embeddables).